# class-validator in nestjs has unexpected behavior for phone numbers in body or route

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I am using [`class-validator`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator) and [`nestjs`](https://nestjs.com/) to preform [validation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation) on my Http requests. I am running into an interesting edge case that I am not sure if it is a bug or my implementation is faulty.

I have two endpoints: 1) to create data with a valid phone number and 2) to retrieve data by a phone number in the route param. It seems like the route param has more strict validation. I am using the `'US'` intl code because my app doesn't support international numbers yet. Here is my implementation:

**Creating Data with Phone Number**

```js
/* contact.dto.ts */
export class ContactDto {
  @IsPhoneNumber('US')
  public phoneNumber: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  public name: string;
}

/* contract.controller.ts */
@Controller('contacts')
export class ContactsController {

  @Post()
  async createContact (
    @Req() request: Request,
    @Res() response: Response,
    @Body() newContact: ContactDto
  ) { 
    // save the data
  }
  // other methods
}
```

In the `@Body()` annotation, I am able to pass in valid 10 or 11 digit phone numbers (with or without punctuation). For example:

```
// all pass in @Body()
{ "phoneNumber": "18005550000", "name": "..." }
{ "phoneNumber": "8005550000", "name": "..." }
{ "phoneNumber": "1 (800) 555-0000", "name": "..." }

// don't pass in @Body()
{ "phoneNumber": "12345678", "name": "..." }
{ "phoneNumber": "123456789012", "name": "..." }
```

**Getting Data from Phone Number**

```js
/* phonenumber.models.ts */
export class FindPhoneNumberParam {
  @IsPhoneNumber('US')
  public phoneNumber: string;
}

/* phone-numbers.controller.ts */
@Controller('phone-numbers')
export class PhoneNumbersController {

  @Get(':phoneNumber')
  async getPhoneNumber (
    @Req() request: Request,
    @Res() response: Response,
    @Param() phoneNumber: FindPhoneNumberParam
  ) {
    // look up and return phone number resource
  }
  // other methods
}
```

In the `@Param()` annotation, it *must* be 11 digits with the `'US'` intl code of `1` at the beginning.

```
// all pass in @Param()
{api}/phone-numbers/18005550000
{api}/phone-numbers/1(800)5550000

// don't pass in @Param()
{api}/phone-numbers/8005550000
{api}/phone-numbers/12345678
{api}/phone-numbers/123456789012
{api}/phone-numbers/98005550000
```

I guess it makes sense that it would require me to pass in the `11` digit `'US'` code with the proceeding `1`, but it just seemed odd to me that `@Body()` and `@Param()` have different behaviors even though they use the same `class-validators` annotation - [`@IsPhoneNumber`](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validation-decorators). Does anyone know about why this would be the case?

Answer (score 0):

updating params should solve the problem. The incorrect parsing is because the params is not parsing it as string whereas in the body you are explicitly passing it as string

```
export class FindPhoneNumberParam {
  @Transform(value => value.toString())
  @IsPhoneNumber('US')
  public phoneNumber: string;
}
```